# Removing an object from a singleton-managed container upon destruction

Tags: c++, singleton, shared-ptr

I have a `Singleton` class that manages a container of `Item`s, exposing public functions that allow `Item`s to be added or removed from the container.

```
class Item;
typedef std::shared_ptr<Item> ItemPtr;

class Singleton
{
public:
  static Singleton& Instance()
  {
    static std::unique_ptr<Singleton> Instance(new Singleton);
    return *Instance;
  }

  void Add(ItemPtr item)
  {
    mContainer.push_back(item);
  }

  void Remove(ItemPtr item)
  {
    for (auto it = mContainer.begin(); it != mContainer.end(); it++)
      if (*it == item)
        mContainer.erase(it);
  }

private:
  std::vector<ItemPtr> mContainer;
};
```

I'd like `Item` to have the ability to add itself to the `Singleton` container via an `Add()` method, and remove itself from the container upon its destruction.

```
class Item
{
public:
  Item() {}

  ~Item() 
  {
    Singleton::Instance().Remove(ItemPtr(this));
  }

  void Add()
  {
    Singleton::Instance().Add(ItemPtr(this));
  }
};
```

When I run the example below, I get a crash on `Singleton::Remove()`, specifically a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on `mContainer.begin()`.

```
int main()
{
  Item* a = new Item();
  Item* b = new Item();

  a->Add();
  b->Add();

  delete a;
  delete b;
}
```

This seems to indicate that `mContainer` no longer exists. Looking at the call stack, I can also see one of the root call stack frames is the destructor `Singleton::~Singleton()`, which would explain why `mContainer` is no longer there.

I've tried a different approach : instead of using `std::shared_ptr<Item>` I simply used raw pointers (i.e., `Item*`) with the appropriate substitutions in the code. It worked without problems.

My questions are:

- I guess what's happening is that the ownership of the `Item` objects is only released by the `shared_ptr` after the destruction of `Singleton`, which causes the error. Is this correct?
- Is it impossible to do what I want to do if the container in `Singleton` is of `shared_ptr<Item>`?
- If not, how could I do it?

Comment: Off the top, `Singleton::Remove` exhibits undefined behavior. `mContainer.erase(it)` invalidates `it`, and then `it++` accesses this now-invalid iterator.

Comment: You may be looking for [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this). `ItemPtr(this)` is a bad idea, as it'll lead to double destruction: `ItemPtr` temporary is destroyed at the semicolon and will call `delete` on `this`.

Comment: The raw pointers `a` and `b` are enshrouded in `std::shared_ptr` instances that are pushed into the container. those naked `delete` calls are *wrong*. Either a dynamic object is managed by smart pointers or it isn't. You can't have it both ways, and you *certainly* cannot have their ultimate destruction done *twice*. You should absolutely look into `enabled_shared_from_this`, and keep in mind, if you go that route any instance request to produce a `std::shared_ptr` *must* be managed from initial creation of said-same from inception.

Comment: How will the object be destructed since the object will always alive in the singleton?  That's a bit circular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wisdom of doing this in the first place notwithstanding, what you want can be achieved if you're willing to use, and abide by the restrictions of, `std::enabled_shared_from_this`. See below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Item;
typedef std::shared_ptr<Item> ItemPtr;

class Singleton
{
private:
    Singleton() {}

public:
    static Singleton &Instance()
    {
        static Singleton s;
        return s;
    }

    void Add(ItemPtr item)
    {
        mContainer.emplace_back(std::move(item));
    }

    void Remove(const ItemPtr& item)
    {
        mContainer.erase(
            std::remove(mContainer.begin(), mContainer.end(), item), 
            mContainer.end());
    }

    void Clear()
    {
        mContainer.clear();
    }

private:
    std::vector<ItemPtr> mContainer;
};

// note derivation. this means you can get a std::shared_ptr<Item>
// via `shared_from_this` , but it also means the object itself
// MUST be an actual shared object to begin with.
struct Item : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Item>
{
    void Add()
    {
        Singleton::Instance().Add(shared_from_this());
    }
};


int main()
{
    ItemPtr a = std::make_shared<Item>();
    ItemPtr b = std::make_shared<Item>();

    // add to the singleton container
    a->Add();
    b->Add();

    // report reference count of 'a'
    std::cout << "before removal 'a' has " << a.use_count() << " references\n";
    Singleton::Instance().Remove(a);
    std::cout << "after removal 'a' has " << a.use_count() << " references\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
before removal 'a' has 2 references
after removal 'a' has 1 references
```

The most important part of this is the creation of `a` and `b` in `main` . Notice they are, in fact, managed by `std::shared_ptr` enshrouding from inception. This is required for `std::enable_shared_from_this` to work correctly. The rest is fairly straight forward. The ability to get a reference-bumped `std::shared_ptr` from *within* the body of any member of `Item` is done via the `shared_from_this()` member provided from the base class `std::enable_shared_from_this`.

In short, taking this approach will work for you, but at no point can you use `shared_from_this()` unless the object it is being fired upon is already managed by a `std::shared_ptr` in the first place. Keep that in mind.